# Opposite of 'contaminate'

Tags: single-word-requests

*Contaminate* (transitive verb) means "to add a little bit of bad stuff to (something), rendering it bad". Or thereabouts.

Is there a word for "to add a little bit of good stuff to (something), rendering it acceptable, not bad"?

Or, less optimal, an intransitive verb, or a noun describing the action?

Comment: It's not, of course, _decontaminate_, which means "to remove the bad stuff that wound up in (something), rendering it good again".

Comment: You could add some sugar to poison, but it wouldn't make it safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Perhaps *remediate*.

But it depends on the "good stuff" that's being added.

Other possibilities:

*strengthen*

*rehabilitate*

I also like @Kevin's *fortify* and *purify* from @MrHen's list.

I think nearly all of @F'x's suggestions are good, and @nico's answers are super-dope as well.

Comment: ...and the check mark. For _remediate_.

Answer (score 11):

You could use *to enrich*, *to supplement*, *to ameliorate*.

In certain contexts (e.g. metallurgy or electronics) you may also use *to dope* (e.g. *doped semiconductors*).

Comment: Re _enrich_ and _supplement_, see my comment on [Kevin's answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19599).

Comment: @msh210: so you want to say that something which was not good before is now good after the addition?

Comment: @nico, I can't find this use of _drug_ in metallurgy in [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=drug+subject%3Ametallurgy&tbm=bks). [_Ameliorate_](http://books.google.com/books?id=I7JNoIcUycQC&pg=PA124&dq=ameliorate) looks good, though; thanks!

Comment: @nico, re your comment: Yes.

Comment: Actually, "ameliorate the water in" and "ameliorate the water of" get no hits on Google Books. Perhaps it's not really the right word at all....

Comment: `Drug` or `dope` is used for instance in semiconductors (such as a `drugged semiconductor`). `Water amilioration` seems to get quite a bit of hits in Google.

Comment: _Drugged semiconductor_ has only seven Google hits on the Web (and, as one might therefore expect, none at all in Google Books). but you seem to be right, @nico, about _water amelioration_. Thanks!

Comment: @msh210: You're right: *doped semiconductor* is the correct English term. I was thinking of the Italian term (`drogaggio`)... and I assumed it was the same in English! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doping_%28semiconductor%29 . I corrected my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Fortify.  As in "fortified with vitamins and nutrients."

Comment: Hm, yes, but that's not quite the meaning I'm looking for. I'm going to edit the question to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

***To enhance***, *to improve*, *to better*, *to augment*, *to boost*, *to refine*, *to purify*, *to strengthen*.

Answer (score 2):

" This unfortunate situation could be ameliorated by the addition of a little charity."

Answer (score 1):

A few options:

- reenforce
- build
- purify
- edit/proofread
- bless
- fix
- flood
- consume

A few nouns:

- magic (specifically black magic or white magic)
- pixie dust
- goodness

Of note, you *can* say "contaminate with goodness" or "infect with happy" or any number of other phrases. They work best when combined with a character or voice that is genre-savvily evil or macho. The apparent collision of connotations works great for comedic or satirical effects.

Answer (score 1):

"To spice up" - won't work in all instances but captures it in some.

Answer (score 1):

The item added could be a [palliative](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/palliative) and would serve to [palliate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/palliate) whatever its being added to.

[Moderated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/moderated)

> The malignancy of this concoction
>   could be moderated with a splash of
>   gin

[Mitgate](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/mitigate)

> The addition of a little antidote to
>   the cup would mitigate the initial
>   effects of the poison diverting
>   suspicion until it was too late!

Mask could work for your edited question.

> The medicine was vile but a little
>   sugar masked it

or

> He masked the bitter poison with honey

Even dilute could work

> He diluted the cheap scotch with coke
>   until it was rendered palatable